# Get last DDL time for Oracle table in different Schema

Tags: oracle

I am trying to find the time of the last DDL statement that has been applied on a table.

I found this solution:

```
Select OBJECT_NAME, LAST_DDL_TIME
From user_objects
Where OBJECT_NAME='MY_TABLE'
```

The problem is: I want to check this for a table which doesn't belong to my Schema.

Any suggestion please

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Assuming you have permissions, you would just need to query the `ALL_OBJECTS` or `DBA_OBJECTS` view, i.e.

```
SELECT object_name, object_type, last_ddl_time
  FROM dba_objects (or all_objects)
 WHERE owner = <<owner of table>>
   AND object_name = 'MY_TABLE'
```

`ALL_OBJECTS` has information about all the objects that you have privileges on (i.e. the tables you can at least SELECT from).  `DBA_OBJECTS` has information about all the objects in the database whether you have permission to access them or not.  However, access to the `DBA_OBJECTS` view requires additional privileges.